# C programming typedef usage

Tags: c

```
typedef void (*Hello)(struct test1 *, test2 *, int a, int b, const int c *, int d);
```

In this case, I am confused by how to handle the struct as the argument.

I have written:

```
Hello p1;
(*p1)(....need some arguments to be added here);
```

Please kindly teach me how to complete this maybe sample code could help.

Thanks

Comment: Start with a simpler `typedef`, say with one argument. Then add more arguments as you get familiar and more confident of how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code

```
struct point {
  int x;
  int y;
};

typedef void (*Hello)(struct point *p);

void resetPoint(struct point *p)
{
  p->x = 10;
  p->y = 0;
}

int main(void)
{
  struct point dot;
  Hello p1 = resetPoint;
  p1(&dot);
  printf("%d\n",dot.x);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Filip. What really confuses me is that  how I can fill strcut test1 * as an argument in this function. Would you mind show me the snippet?

Comment: Sure, inside main `struct point dot;` then `resetPoint(&dot);` if you are using typedef Hello, then `Hello p1 = resetPoint;` and `p1(&dot);`

Comment: would you please update your answer so that I can avoid misunderstanding what you mean.